# Make image not wrap on small monitors

Tags: css, html

Having a problem where on small monitors the image wraps to the next line is there a way to make it stay on the same line and just have the scrollbar appear to see all of the image or something?

```
<body style="font-name:Arial,Helvetica;font-size:10pt">
   <h1>Order Confirmation</h1>  
     <img src="http://www.new-line.com/catalog/images/nlbanner1.png" /><img src="http://www.new-line.com/catalog/images/nlbanner2.png" />
```

http://www.new-line.com/catalog/images/nlbanner1.pnghttp://www.new-line.com/catalog/images/nlbanner2.png

It is doing this, but I want the nlbanner 2 to be beside nlbanner1 on the same line. It looks great on large monitors but small ones and mobile seem to have this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `div` around the image:

```
<div class="pic">
   <img src="http://www.new-line.com/catalog/images/nlbanner1.png" /><img src="http://www.new-line.com/catalog/images/nlbanner2.png" />
</div>
```

Then with CSS:

```
.pic {
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
```

Like Charles380 mentioned, if you want the scroll functionality, use:

```
.pic {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;  
}
```

Note that this will also cause the scrollbars to appear, which may not fit with the look you want.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4h2h/)

Comment: you could also add an overflow: scroll; so that it will keep the proper height, which can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/p4h2h/1/

Comment: of course you could always just set a specific height on .pic if it's a know height and overflow hidden. as witnessed by this http://jsfiddle.net/p4h2h/2/ lol aren't I a stinker